# How to escape quotation marks in Enterprise Architect Code Generation Template

Tags: code-generation, enterprise-architect, escaping

I want to give enumeration values a further description. Therefore I'm adding a custom *Tagged Value* to the attributes of the enumeration called **Description**, if a description shall be provided. The goal is, to add a custom C# attribute to the tagged *enumeration attribute* during code generation, but only if such a *Tagged Value* exists. Therefore I need to edit the code generation template for *Attribute Declaration*. Currently it works using:

```
$hasDescription = %attTag:"Description" ? "true" : "false"%
%if $hasDescription == "true"%
[Description(%qt%%attTag:"Description"%%qt%)]
%endIf%
```

which gives me the desired output. But if there are quotation marks in the value, it breaks the output code file. It won't compile. Therefore I need to replace/escape all quotation marks in the value field of the *Tagged Value*. I tried the following (in various combinations):

```
%REPLACE(attTag:"Description", "\"", "\\\"")%
%REPLACE(attTag:"Description", """", "\\""")%
%REPLACE(attTag:"Description", "%qt%", "%sl%%qt%")%
%REPLACE(attTag:"Description", %qt%, %sl%%qt%)%
```

**Note:** `%qt%` is used to insert `"`, `%sl%` is used to insert `\` ([reference](http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/enterprise_architect_user_guide/13.5/model_domains/literaltext.html))

None of them works. Either the string as it is will be inserted into the generated code file or nothing happens to the quotation marks in the value of *Tagged Value*.

So is there a way to escape those characters to be able to replace them in a string within a Code Template?

---

Using Enterprise Architect 13.5.1351

Question asked first on [SE Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/369796/303744)

Comment: I remember this has been asked on Sparx forum and I tried to figure it out (also from that rubbish they call Help), but to no avail. I'd recommend to stay away from that gibberish macro language and use the API to generate code. That's way simpler and you have all freedom you want.

Comment: @ThomasKilian I found a way to achieve, what I wanted. What do you mean by _use the API to generate code_? I'm fairly new to EA and just used the first command I found when I was looking for _generate code_. Do you have some resources on your hand to provide some information for me?

Comment: Now I remember the %qt% again ;-) I don't have a public resource, but what I did is to grab a package and get the classes out of it. For a class you create a class frame (with `write` statements) and inside you expand operations and attributes/associations and operations. That's pretty much straight fwd. I could sketch up some pseudo code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked through the other templates provided and finally found the solution after some more fiddling. The macro take either some text in quotation marks or variables as parameters. Since using the escape sequences directly in the `REPLACE` macro didn't work, I tried assigning them to variables beforehand:

```
$qt = %qt%
$escape = %sl% + %qt%
$description = %REPLACE(attTag:"Description", $qt, $escape)%
```

That's it. Finally works. It is important to add the `+` between `%sl%` and `%qt%` on the second line, even though the [documentation on *Code Template Syntax* > *Literal Text*](https://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/10/extending_uml_models/literaltext.html) states it otherwise. `$escape = %sl%%qt%` does not work, as it yields me just a `\` without the `"`.

The variable `$description` is not necessary, but added for readability.